# How to use if condition inside if

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I want to use an `If()` inside an `If()` statement. Is it possible without putting `Else()` before.

My Code:

```
For i = 3 To 24
  If i < 25 Then
    sourcef = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("B" & i)
    fname = "Z:\ISC-Product Costing\Manufacturing Controlling\03_BUDGETS\2019\Chocolate\OP'19\Reporting\Plant Submission\OP'19 Deck " & sourcef & ".xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open fname, UpdateLinks:=0
    Set wC3 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wC1 = wC3.Sheets("Conversion P&L")
    Set wC2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sourcef)
    Sheets("Conversion P&L").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets(sourcef).Select
    Call CompareColumns
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "EUR"
    Range("B2").Select
    ("some more Code")

    wC3.Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=False
  Else
  End If
Next i

(some more code)
End Sub
```

I want to add one more `If` after `Call CompareColumns`. How to do it?

`Call CompareColumns` is another macro in which value for "same" will be defined as True or False. I want to add `If Same = True then` "Code continues" `Else` go to `wc3. Activate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as much 'If' as you want. And you also dont need to use the else case.

```
If .... Then

   If .... Then
   ....
   Else
   ....
   End If

End If
```

In your case:

```
If i < 25 Then
   Code...
 If i < 25 Then
   Call CompareColumns
   Rest of code....
 Else 
  wc3.Activate
  Rest of code....
 End If
End If
```

Comment: As this answer also clearly shows, is the clarity, caused by the indentation. Indenting your source code might reduce confusion drastically.

Comment: @Dominique Yes thanks.... I am preparing this code for so long that I started getting lost in it. The issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more if you can use select case:
i.e.

```
Select Case yourInput
    Case Is <= 25
        'your code
    Case Is >= 70
        'your code
    Case Else
        'your code
End Select
```